# IOS App Validation errors: Non Public API usage and access the UDID

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store-connect, udid

While attempting to upload my apps binary to iTunes Connect, I get errors when I validate my app. The errors are:

**- Your app contains non-public API usage.**

**- Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice**

I have gone through several similar S.O. questions, such as:
- [non-public API usage Warning...preventing validation on upload to App store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939311/non-public-api-usage-warning-preventing-validation-on-upload-to-app-store)
- [App rejected, but I don't use UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid)
- [Binary rejected because of Non-public API usage (google analytic iOSv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434115/binary-rejected-because-of-non-public-api-usage-google-analytic-iosv2)

As far as I know, my app only uses the Flurry API and Google AdMob API. I have updated both of those with no change.

When I used the command `grep -Rnis 'uniqueIdentifier' *` I get the following:

`Binary file BroncoMobile [CURRENT]/BroncoMobile/BroncoMobile.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/oit.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches`

`Binary file Bronco Mobile [CURRENT]/BroncoMobile/libGoogleAdMobAds.a matches`

The match with `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` makes me assume that there is still a problem with the GADMob API, and I'm not sure on how the `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` match could cause problems with validation (or how to fix it if it is the problem).

If there are any more suggestions for how I can find the source of the error in the validation that would be greatly appreciated. If there is any more information I can provide about my app, I would be more than willing to edit my question to include whatever is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to double check to make sure you are using latest version of Google AdMob API. I faced the similar problem in past and fixed it only by using latest Google AdMob SDK.

Also, you may like to check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid).

Comment: Yup, I have updated to the lastest version of Google AdMob API twice now, just to make sure that the issue was not related to that.

Comment: Under "Build Settings", make sure that "Library Search Paths" does not point to any older versions of the SDK.

Comment: Oh, that might be the source of the problem, there were several older versions that were pointed to. Give me a moment to rebuild, archive, and revalidate.

Comment: I LOVE YOU SO MUCH! Seriously, you are my new hero! Only time will tell if my app is not rejected from the app store, but at least it passed validation!

Comment: This does NOT work anymore as of this posting. libGoogleAdMobAds.a (among others) uses -destroy which is now a non public API. Will need to wait for AdMob SDK update.