# Xcode: How to update AdMob

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, ads, xcode5

I have to update the Google AdMob SDK in my apps.
I have downloaded the latest SDK and replaced the old Admob files in the project with the new ones. When I run the app, the ads works but I get two warnings saying that they couldn't find certain files.(It is files from the old SDK folder).

How do I get Xcode to understand that it should look for the file in the new SDK folder? :)

/a noob

Answer (score 2):

I would check out this question for some of your answer:

[IOS App Validation errors: Non Public API usage and access the UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17932248/1759409)

The key point is, as AnkitJain says, "Under "Build Settings", make sure that "Library Search Paths" does not point to any older versions of the SDK."

Comment: thanks bro for your answer. I was struggling with this for long. Thanks buddy.